# pass a c# variable to javascript function

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to pass a c# variable as an argument to a java-script function like

```
<%var count=model.SomeMode.Count();%>
```

when i pass it to my java script function "checkAll(count)" it does not fire but without the argument its workin fine

```
<a  href="#" onclick="return checkAll(count);">CheckAll</a>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remember the page gets created however you wish.  So, you could do something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var count = <%=model.SomeMode.Count(); %>;
</script>
```

You could apply the same logic in method calls, so you could do:

```
<a  href="#" onclick="return checkAll(<%=model.SomeMode.Count(); %>);">CheckAll</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Javascript can't see your C# source directly - you need to write it into the Javascript source on the server side:

```
<a  href="#" onclick="return checkAll(<%= count %>);">CheckAll</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

It should look like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var count=<%=model.SomeMode.Count()%>;
</script>
```

Currently you're declaring your variable in C#, not outputting it in the page as a JavaScript one. Instead, you want to declare `var count` literally in the page and have it set to the output of `model.SomeMode.Count()`.

Answer (score 0):

This might be good for your solution:

```
<a  href="#" onclick='return checkAll(<%=count%);'>CheckAll</a>
```

But there is an other way of doing this instead of conventional way:

[Sharing Variables Between JavaScript and C#](http://iridescence.no/post/Sharing-Variables-Between-JavaScript-and-C.aspx) by [Fredrik Kalseth](http://iridescence.no/)