# pass a javascript variable to c# function

Tags: c#, javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [convert javascript variable to C# variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7751303/convert-javascript-variable-to-c-sharp-variable)

I have a c# code in which JavaScript code is embedded. I need to pass the variable label to  C# function.. Is this possible? if then how can I achieve it?

```
StringBuilder ts = new StringBuilder("<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>");
ts.Append(var label="testLabel";);
ts.Append("</script>");  
HtmlGenericControl div = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
div.Attributes.Add("id",DivId);
div.InnerHtml = ts.ToString();
Container.Controls.Add(div);
```

Comment: This is a dup of MANY questions

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4153329/pass-a-c-sharp-variable-to-javascript-function?rq=1

Comment: @ClintonWard: That's the *other* direction.  Have a concrete dup of JS -> C#?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7751303/convert-javascript-variable-to-c-sharp-variable?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

No C# is server side. JS is client side. Unless you are talking about a WebControl or something. Otherwise the closest is AJAX

Comment: Can you please tell how can i do it using ajax? any example links?

Answer (score 0):

Check code below ...

```
`StringBuilder ts = new StringBuilder("<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>");
 ts.Append("var label='testLabel';");
 ts.Append("</script>");  
 HtmlGenericControl div = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
 div.Attributes.Add("id",DivId);
 div.InnerHtml = ts.ToString();
 Container.Controls.Add(div);
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Response.Write(ts.ToString()); in your aspx if you have one