# How to Pass a c# variable to javascript in Blazor Web Assembly

Tags: javascript, c#, blazor-webassembly

I am using Blazor Web assembly and the 3rd party component does not support @onitnput , @bind-value:event="oninput". To try and get around this I am attempting to use JS to trigger a c# function. (I have other stuff that is triggering the "onchange" on input so when you look at my example just think of it as oninput, and that is working).

**Main issue:**
I need to pass a reference to the page into the method being called by onchange so that I can then call the c# method from JS but I can't get it to pass the parameter.
Here is my markup

```
<RadzenHtmlEditor @bind-Value=@SurveyScriptNode.Script onchange="callCSharpMethodNoParams(@DotNetObjectReference.Create(this))" style="height: 500px; margin-bottom: 1rem; opacity: 1;" UploadUrl="upload/image" Paste=@OnPaste Execute=@OnExecute id="scriptBuilder_surveyScriptNode_ScriptEditor">
```

I also tried what was suggested [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4153329/pass-a-c-sharp-variable-to-javascript-function) but could not get it working either

```
<RadzenHtmlEditor @bind-Value=@SurveyScriptNode.Script onchange="callCSharpMethodNoParams(<%=DotNetObjectReference.Create(this)%>)" style="height: 500px; margin-bottom: 1rem; opacity: 1;" UploadUrl="upload/image" Paste=@OnPaste Execute=@OnExecute id="scriptBuilder_surveyScriptNode_ScriptEditor">
```

Is there any way to do this in Blazor?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I don't really understand the purpose of all this.  What does the `callCSharpMethodNoParams` method do that you can't do in C#?

Comment: Well the issue is that the RadzenHTMLEditor (Rich text Box) won't allow me to use @oninput   which is normally how you would trigger a method while typing in a textarea / text box in blazor web assembly. There is another way of triggering onInput in blazor but it does not work either. So I need to use a JS oninput to call my c# method. To do that I need to a c# variable to a js function in the normal oninput (onclick in my posted example) of the component.

Comment: What I am trying to do is show a "You have unsaved changes" banner whenever the user makes changes to a record. One of the first things I tried was what you are suggesting however the setter does not get called either until the control loses focus (i confirmed this by putting a break point in my setter method). Waiting to show the banner until after the control loses focus is not desirable because they will be working in these forms during downtime  between emergency alarms so there is a chance that if they made an edit, worked and alarm, and came back, they may think it is saved and close tab

Comment: Okay I've got it now.  Getting the reference to the `<RadzenHtmlEditor>` probably won't help you anyway, since the actual input that you want the event for will be a child to it.  I don't have Radzen installed, but have you inspected the rendered html?  Does the actual input have some kind of unique ID or class name that you could use in JavaScript to attach an event handler?

Comment: I have not looked at the render HTML and will probably have to wait until Monday to do so. I can say that I am able to define and ID on the Component and as a little test I was able to use JsInterop to add a Oninput listener to the component, that oninput calls the normal onclick and I got a test js method to fire inside of that onclick as I typed. If I can get that "DotNetObjectReference.Create(this)" passed to the jsmethod via the onclick I am 90% sure I can get this working (I know I should change the onclick to oninput instead of the round about way I am doing it.)

Comment: Floating an alternate idea-- autosave every 10 seconds.  Text transfers are cheap-- you could update an entire book every 10 seconds, and it would cost less than serving a low-resolution image.

Comment: That's not a bad idea but that leaves room for accidental deletions being saved which is worse then the new work not getting saved, they run the scripts through tests to make sure they are correct but if they accidently deleted and forgot that it auto saved so no test was run it could cost a client their life. I spoke to My BA though and she said she will let the Managers know that the banner won't show up until the controls lose focus until I can re-visit this later on. Thank you for taking the time to try and help, hopefully I can think up something in a few months when I revisit this.

Comment: In that case, just copy what other apps do-- autosave with multiple versions, and then save-on-demand.

Comment: I actually figured out a decent workaround and got it implemented that I am going to post as the answer so that there is not a character limit. Your auto save suggestion got timers in my head and which is how I came up with a solution so thank you again for all the help

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround I am doing this:

- Hide a check box
- Set a js oninput method on the desired control, this will
  call a js function that sets the hidden check box to true
- Since the hidden checkbox can't @bind when JS updates the value and it will not update the value when calling StateHasChanged(),  you need to implement a timer that uses JS interop to call a js function to return the value of the hidden check box to your c# code.
- Set the value of the c# variable to the returned value of the previous step
- Create another method in the c# that uses JS Interop to call the js function you use in your on input, call this method in the setter of the c# variable but make sure to only do it if the page is already initialized.